# How can i pass an image from client to server in dart? I am using uno (for http request) and shelf_modular (for server) packages

Tags: flutter, dart

I dont know how to pass images to the server (other types of data i do). Per example, the following function:

```
  Future<void> storeImage() async {
    final uno = locator.get<Uno>();
    final url = Uri.parse('/image/store/');
    final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image-try.jpg');
    final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Response response = await uno.post(url.toString(),
        data: list,
        headers: {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'},
        responseType: ResponseType.arraybuffer);
    print(response);
  }
```

Uno is a singleton with the right default configurations such as server path and so on.

this function doesnt even reach my handler function inside my Resource class. i get an error Uno 404.

then in the server i would get the image how?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf_modular/shelf_modular.dart';

class ImagesResource extends Resource {
  @override
  List<Route> get routes => [
        Route.post('/image/store', _store),
        Route.get('/image/get/:id', _get),
      ];

  FutureOr<Response> _store(
      ModularArguments arguments, Injector injector) async {
    try {
      // Get the image file from the request body.
      final imageList = arguments.data as Uint8List;
      // Create a new file on disk to store the image.
      final newFile = File('./images/randomfilename');
      // Write the image data to the new file.
      await newFile.writeAsBytes(imageList);
      // Return a successful response.
      return Response.ok(jsonEncode('ok'));
    } catch (e) {
      // Return an error response.
      return Response.internalServerError(body: jsonEncode(e));
    }
  }

  FutureOr<Response> _get(ModularArguments arguments, Injector injector) async {
    try {
      // Get the image ID from the request path.
      final id = arguments.params['id'];

      // Create a new file object for the image file.
      final imageFile = File('./images/$id');

      // Read the image data from the file.
      final imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();

      // Return a successful response with the image data.
      return Response.ok(imageBytes);
    } catch (e) {
      // Return an error response.
      return Response.internalServerError(body: jsonEncode(e));
    }
  }
}
```

learn how to send images to the server from the client and also from server to client using uno and shelf_modular packages